# Array com um arquivo de texto

Tags: php

Olá,

Preciso de um método que o PHP irá ler um arquivo de texto. Um exemplo do que o arquivo irá conter:

```
none|link
```

Sendo assim, quando o PHP terminar de ler o arquivo, ele dá uma array com o nome e o link, por exemplo:

```
<?php
$conteudo = array('nome' => 'link');
?>
```

Procurei na internet mas não achei.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução seria ler o arquivo linha por linha e ir adicionando ao array:

```
   <?php
    $arq = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'r');
    $conteudo = array();
    if( $arq ) {
        while( ( $linha = fgets( $arq ) ) !== false )
        {
            $keyValue = explode( '|', $linha, 2 );
            if( count( $keyValue ) === 2 )
            {
                $key = $keyValue[0];
                $value = $keyValue[1];
                $conteudo[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        fclose( $arq );
    }
    else
    {
        die('Erro ao abrir arquivo!');
    }
```

Comment: Opa! Deu certinho aqui, valeuzão!!

Answer (score 4):

Execute o código abaixo, onde "nomedoarquivo.txt" é o nome do seu arquivo a ser lido. O array estará armazenado na variável `$conteudo`

```
$conteudo = array();
$f = fopen("nomedoarquivo.txt", "r");
while ($linha = fgetcsv($f, 0, '|'))
{
    // retira o primeiro elemento do array, retornando-o para a variável $chave
    $chave = array_shift($linha);
    // associa a chave determinada na linha anterior o elemento restante do array
    $conteudo[$chave] = $linha;
}
fclose($f);
var_dump($conteudo);
```

Comment: Deu um erro aqui:

Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\_\teste2.php on line 3

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\_\teste2.php on line 4

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\_\teste2.php on line 11
array(0) { }

Comment: Olá, atualizei o código colocando o parâmetro de qual o modo de abertura do arquivo. No caso, leitura.

Comment: Agora deu certo, mas o amigo ali conseguiu me ajudar mais rápido, mas mesmo assim, valeu!!

Comment: Note que a minha solução é mais compacta e elegante. Mas fica a seu critério escolher a correta 